# What's the best approach in Android for disabling all peripheral ports for certain applications?

Tags: java, android, android-source

My company has their own Android tablets created by an OEM partner and we are using custom ROM based on Android 11. The stakeholders have a strange requirement now. They want to allow only our applications (identified by bundle id) to have access to printers and bar code scanners connected to the peripheral ports. Users are allowed to install any application of their choice from the Playstore and they will function normally but when it comes to printing or scanning via peripheral ports, it shouldn't work.

We have full control over the AOSP build and can do whatever we want to ensure above requirements are met. I have no clue where to start and I appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: That's a fine question, but Stack Overflow tends to be better for app development questions. I recommend trying the forums at XDA or other venues more tied to custom ROM development.

Comment: Two choices: 1, define an private android permission, which is protected by signature or system, and it only can be used by private apps in rom. You should find the proper place to check whether the app has the permission. 2. use sepolicy. label the peripheral devices with new defined label, and add rule to allow priv-app to access it, so that third app will not be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks @Yong. That's indeed a good start for me. I think I will go with option number 2. Instead of priv-apps can I define the rule based on something else. Because our own apps are not bundled as priv-apps